# Different color in different matrix elements using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following codes,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.genfromtxt("matrix.txt");

data_new = data.reshape([1000,1000])

ax.matshow(data_new)
```

How can I define the color for the numerical range of the density matrix elements?
For example,

```
Red     : > 0.1

Blue    : 0.01-0.1

Magenta : 0.001-0.01

Yellow  : 0.0001-0.001

Brown   : 0.00001-0.0001

Green   : 0.000001-0.00001

Gray    : < 0.000001
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask of how you would like your matrix to be coloured

```
mask = np.zeros(data_new.shape)
// add your actual constraints or mapping here, for example
mask[data_new > 0.5] = 1
mask[data_new <= 0.5] = 2
```

and if you are particularly set on those colours create/use a cmap for them

```
from matplotlib import cm
...

plt.matshow(mask, cmap=cm.Reds)
plt.show()
```

https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/pyplot_summary.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps